# How do I use the rope dart?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Could someone tell me how to use the rope dart properly? I use it, but struggle with finding out how to do different moves consistently with it.

Especially wondering how to "catch" people and pull them in with it. He does it some seldom times, but mostly the target just falls backwards on the ground and gets back up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the rope dart, everything is contextual.

If you are in open conflict, using the rope dart will simply snare a target and yank them toward you and they'll fall to the ground.  If you're close enough to them when they've fallen, you can perform a ground kill on them.

If you are anonymous (not in open conflict), you have a few more options.  You will do this as long as you remain undetected as you do these actions.

When on the ground, using the rope dart and holding the button down, you will pull them toward you.  The longer you hold it, the more you will pull them closer.  When the target is close enough, you will perform a kill on them.  This works best if you're in a stealth location (e.g., bushes, tall grass, etc.) to reduce the chances of being detected after the kill.  If you happen to get detected after the initial pull, you may continue to pull them and will still kill them when close.

When on higher ground, using the rope dart and holding the button down, you will pull them toward you.  When they can no longer be pulled anymore (when they're directly underneath you or blocked by an obstruction), you will start choking them.  Doing this will grant you a silent kill (not alerting anyone).

When on a beam (i.e., a branch, a rope, etc.), using the rope dart and holding the button down, you will perform the same action if you were on higher ground.  If however you move off of the beam while holding the button, you will perform a predator move hanging the target.  You will lose one of your rope darts.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but it seems to differ if you hit them from the front and from the back too. When I'm on the ground, in hiding, and hit them from behind, he seems to consistently pull them back as long as I keep holding Y.

Comment: Well yeah, trying to hit them from the front where they can see you, you'll get detected (forcing open conflict). Getting them from behind (where nobody else can see either you or the target) will generally be safe. Using the rope dart from the grass will still make you detectable (since you are technically in high profile). It's just meant to hide your killed target.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pull people all the way to you, you can only pull them a small distance toward you. You do this by "shooting" the rope dart, and then pressing on the back movement (<kbd>S</kbd> on the PC).

The one exception to this, is when you are located on a branch of a tree. Doing the same move, shooting the rope dart, and then pressing a movement button, will hang your target from the tree branch and kill them.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought there was another case where you can use the rope dart to do a hanging kill.  Must it be a tree branch?

Comment: @MarkRogers It'll probably work on a wooden beam or something too as long as it's thin and above an enemy?

Comment: The thing is that I've seen him pull enemies all the way towards me and then finish them off with a dagger. But I can't figure out when. Might be in connection with being in hiding or something, but was hoping someone knew for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an open conflict and have at least 3 enemies surrounding you by holding the triangle button you can also perform a double kill.I have done this some times and you don't lose your rope dart

Answer (score 0):

During open conflict, when you counter an enemy hit "Y" on xbox immediately after you counter and Connor will perform a kill with your rope dart, providing they are your equipped ranged weapon. You will lose one of your rope darts.